# Obter somente nome do arquivo do pathlib

Tags: python, string, path, substring

Atualmente tenho o seguinte código:

```python
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path("resources/maps").glob("*.json"):
    print(file)
```

O qual retorna:

```
resources\maps\map1.json
resources\maps\map2.json
resources\maps\map3.json
```

Porém eu preciso apenas do nome do arquivo, e não do caminho inteiro até ele...

Existe algum método do próprio pathlib para isso?

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path("resources/maps").glob("*.json"):
    print(file.name)
```

[Documentação (em inglês)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name)

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/112052

Comment: Eu só tentei explicar como o site funciona e como melhorar suas respostas (na hora eu estava com pouco tempo pra explicar melhor, então só deixei um link). É uma pena que vc não queira entender. Mas vou tentar de novo e sugerir outro link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct - sugiro que leia e reveja sua postura, e encare meus comentários como críticas construtivas. Até mais